# Lightroom - Computer run out of memory when creating slideshow video over 1200 photos

Tags: lightroom, video, slideshow, export

As the title says, when I tried to export video (1080p) from a slideshow created in Lightroom (1200 photos), my Mac threw warning that the application memory had run out :(. So far I have tried to delete the cache, restart, even turn-off turn-on my laptop but none has worked.

I already did so much processing and ordering in Lightroom, so I hoped I do not have to switch to different application and start from scratch. Has anyone encounter the same problem? What did you do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the application so much as it is the size of the data you are including. You've got two basic choices:

- Add more RAM to your machine. You need enough to load all of the images at the same time. I'm not a MAC guy, but you may also be able to increase the amount of disk space allocated as "virtual memory" (Swap).
- Divide the show into several smaller segments. You can probably copy the project (which is just a set of instructions about what to include when the video is rendered), then delete a portion from each copy until you find a size small enough that your machine can handle it.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Michael Clark, in the end I followed your suggestion to break the whole set into smaller videos and merge them later. Do you have suggestion on which application is better for creating video? I found out that I could not assign different duration for each photo in Lightroom, also could not delay when the audio plays :(

Comment: I'm a windows guy. All three of the applications I use/have used to make photo slideshows with customizable durations/transitions/audio cues are Windows only programs. Sorry. That might be a good question to ask here in its own right: What MAC compatible applications allow one to create a photo slideshow with varying lengths and adjustable audio cues?

Comment: @Danny Glad my suggestion worked for you!